# Upgrading from Entity Framework 6 to EF Core moving to AspNetCore.Identity dealing with schema migration issues with existing databases

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, entity-framework-migrations

We are in the process of upgrading a large multi-tenant application (single web app with multiple databases that have identical schema) from .Net Framework 4.8 to .Net 6, this includes moving from Entity Framework 6 to Entity Framework Core 7 which also means moving from Asp.Net Identity to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.

The original project used code first Automatic Migrations for database updates which always worked great but this isn't available in EF Core so we need to setup manual migrations, therefore, the issue is we need to use the original databases and the same schema as must as possible, creating new databases and copying over the data from one to another isn't really viable due to the amount of databases and data involved and there cannot be any downtime.

The issue is that to get it to the point where the solution will currently build means we have changed from Asp.Net Identity to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity, this has resulted in changes to some database tables such as the adding of the "NormalisedUsername" etc fields in the AspNetUsers table as well as other changes.

We therefore need to potentially create an initial migration of the database in Entity Framework that will only include the changes that have been made by the upgrade to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity so that this can be run against the databases initially then going forward we can create new "migrations" for actual changes to the model that we make.

As well as the database changes that have been forced upon us by the move to AspNetCore.Identity it seems that EF Core makes various other changes to the schema of an old EF6 database such as changing Date columns from "datetime" to "datetime2", changes to foreign key and index names etc etc, I am not sure how much of an effect these would have on the running of the application if they are ignored (i.e. not rolled out to existing databases).

There is the other issue of creating new databases going forward but I assume that once we have migrated the existing databases we can possible create a new initial migration that will create all tables in an empty database (however this problem is something that can be looked at later on once we have got past the current issue).

Does anyone have any suggestions as the best way to tackle this problem, basically I think we need to get an initial Entity Framework migration setup that only performs the changes to the current database that have happened due to the framework upgrades and then we can go from there with other model changes that we make but what is the best way to do this, do we have to create a manual migration script by comparing the schemas from an old database and a fresh one created with updated application or is there some tool or trick for generating the initial migration script?

Comment: Hi @Bonio, have you check and try the official doc: [Migrate Authentication and Identity to ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

Comment: @Rena yes I have been through that documentation, it was used to help get the migration as far as it is now, however it has no mention of Entity Framework migrations when using an existing database that was built on EF6 with Asp.net Identity.

Comment: Some ideas: 1) Scaffold current database by EF Core, generate initial migration from scaffolded (internet is full how to do that), 2) Drop everything scaffolded or remember what is needed for additional configuring (initial migration remain). 3) Generate next migration from your current classes - analyze generated migration and correct your mapping.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have already created a scaffold from the current database in a test project and I was using it to check the OnModelCreating and using it to copy over some of the code to my project to make things like the primary key names match etc such as:
entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_dbo.ApplicationUsers"); 
I'm not sure I fully understand the rest of your instructions, are you saying 1) Create a scaffold and generate a migration from this. 2) Delete all the models that it generated but keep the migration script... then I am not sure I follow what you mean to do after that?

Comment: Ok, you have scaffolded, then generate `InitialMigration` which creates all tables from scaffolded model. Copy this migration to your real EF Core project, maybe you have to correct namespaces in snapshot file. Real project has it's own model and `OnModelCreating`. Add migration again (name it `UpdateToEFCore`). EF Core compares snapshot file and current model, it will create new migration to Update current database to your current model.  Check this migration if it has table renames,  columns altering, correct your `OnModelCreating`, remove `UpdateToEFCore` and then add migration again.

Comment: Repeat these steps until your migration `UpdateToEFCore` will be suitable for your needs. Then before applying migrations to Existing database with data, insert into `__EFMigrationsHistory` table record that `InitialMigration` is applied. For new databases, migrations will create new DB with applied all migrations.

Comment: For `DateTime` columns you can specify conventions. Override `ConfigureConventions` and write something like this: `configurationBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().HaveColumnType("datetime");`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Amazing thank you, I still have some further testing to do but so far it looks like what you have suggested should hopefully do what I need. I will write up a full answer of the steps I have been running through once I have finished going through them all.

Comment: Well, I hope this approach will help someone else. Don't forget to create answer ;)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv whilst I have managed to be able to get an initial migration that will create a perfect copy of the schema of my original database, when I create the "UpdateToEFCore" migration at the start of the migration file it is trying to drop a load of foreign keys that don't actually exist therefore the migration falls when I try and run it. Any idea why this would be and how I can stop it or should I just modify the migration file to remove these changes or will that affect future migration files that I create?

Comment: I would suggest to correct your `OnModelCreating` and specify names for foreign keys via `.HasConstraintName("EF6_FK_Name")`. It can be painful if you have a lot of them.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv After testing again this morning I was able to get it to work without needing to set the constraint name manually. I will write up my answer today with all the steps I went through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the great help from @SvyatoslavDanyliv in the comments, I was able to put together the following steps to get this working:

### **Setup a dummy project and generate models and database context based on your current (i.e. old) database schema.**

1. Create a new empty "dummy" .NET Core project in Visual Studio with the same
   framework etc as your live project.
2. Install following packages via NuGet:
   **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools** and
   **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**, ensuring they match the
   versions you have installed in your live project.
3. Generate models and database context in the new dummy project by running
   the following command in the Package Manager console against your live database:

> Scaffold-DbContext 'Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx’
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

### **Generate migration file and snapshot in the new dummy project based on your old database schema:**

Run the following in the Package Manager Console:

> Add-Migration -Name Initial

### Generate a migration file in your live project:

Go back to your live project and run the following in the Package Manager console:

> Add-Migration -Name Initial

### Overwrite the migration files in your live project with the ones from your dummy project

1. Copy the code from the "Initial" migration file in your dummy
   project and overwrite the code in the migration file in your live
   project, updating any namespaces.
2. Copy the code from the "BuildModel" method in the dummy project and
   overwrite it in the live project, you may need to update some namespaces within the code of the BuildModel method so take a look and run a find and replace as necessary.

---

*********Make a copy of the updated snapshot file in your live project, you may need this later to save having to keep copying from the dummy project and overwriting the namespaces each time.*******

---

### Review your OnModelCreating in both projects and then create a blank database from your migration file in the live project

Review the "OnModelCreating" part of the DbContext in the dummy project and make necessary adjustments to your live project to ensure consistency with anything you might need to copy over. One example was I needed to copy over the following to stop it trying to change the collation:

```
modelBuilder.UseCollation("SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS");
```

1. Create a blank database and point the connection string in your live
   project to it then run: ***Update-Database***
2. Compare schemas between your live (i.e. old) database and the new database you just created using the SQL Server schema comparison tool in Visual Studio.
3. Make necessary changes to the Initial migration file and possibly the "OnModelCreating" in your live
   project if schemas don't match perfectly.
4. Delete all tables in the new dummy database. **DO NOT** run
   Remove-Migration as this will delete your migration file as well.
5. Run ***Update-Database*** again
6. Repeat steps 2 - 5 until the migration file creates a perfect copy
   of your original database schema (apart from maybe changes regarding the migration tables).

### Create another migration to include changes for EF Core and AspNetCore.Identity.

Now that you have a migration file that will create a perfect copy of your original database, you can run: ***Add-Migration -Name UpdateToEFCore***

This should create a new migration file that just has the differences between your old schema and the new schema (i.e. changes since upgrading to EF Core etc).

Create an __EFMigrationsHistory table in your live database (well ideally a copy of your live database, you don't want to be running this on your live database yet), you can see the schema for this table from the test database you updated above, add an entry for "Initial" matching what was added to your test database above. This will make your "live" database think that the "Intial" migration has already been run on it.

Change the connection string in your project to point to your "live" database and run ***Update-Database*** against your live database. It should only apply the "UpdateToEFCore" changes.

If you have any problems and need to make some further changes to your "OnModelCreating" etc to get the last migration to work properly you can delete the "UpdateToEFCore" migration file and overwrite the snapshot file with the saved copy I mentioned above. Make any changes to OnModelCreating and recreate the "UpdateToEFCore" migration then run through the steps to run the "UpdateToEFCore" migration again.