# Different tool to generate codefirst migration. Time to clean up and refactor

Tags: ef-code-first, code-first, fluent-migrator, linq2db

I've inherited a non-complete clean solution from the point of view of CodeFist on a .NET 7 project.

The scenario is the following:

- I had an old part of the Codebase that used EF Code first migration
- At the time I used for new migration [FluentMigrator](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/) 5 (and started using [Linq2Db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) as ORM since EF was performing slowly)
- I don't have a full Codefirst script so I cannot use it for sampling a test DB. I need to restore it and then apply migration
- With Net8 I would like to go back to EF, so I can take advantage of the optimizations and use EF Inmemory DB.
- We are using SQLServer on Azure

I was wondering if there's a simple way to create migration for the entire DB so I can have the possibility to create it on the fly. The ideal way would be to use FluentMigrator since I and the colleagues are used to it. For me, it's also correct to say let's start from Day-0 and with an initial scripted DB to restart writing new migration from 0. We have a mono database, we can say that all applied migrations from the beginning are a part of the initial one.

Has anyone of you had to face a similar situation?

Comment: Scaffold via [ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools), then create initial migration. It will contain all tables create scripts. I don't know which tools exists for FluentMigrator. *EF Inmemory DB* - bad idea.  Also check this [experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77958168/upgrading-from-entity-framework-6-to-ef-core-moving-to-aspnetcore-identity-deali)

Comment: Anyway, no serious optimizations in EF Core 8 - `linq2db` two times faster as per our performance tests.